# Remove all lines after line contains?

Tags: linux, sed

I have a script which I want to delete every line after a specific line.

I have a command, but it just wipes the entire file?

`sed -n '/twm &/q;p' ~/.xinitrc > ~/.xinitrc`

Convert something like:

```
some line
another line


some other line
twm &
more lines to be deleted
and more
```

To

```
some line
another line


some other line
```

Answer (score 0):

Since the parent process (your shell) sets up redirection *before* your `sed` command runs, the `> ~/.xinitrc` clears the file before you can read it.

Read `man sed`, and do something like *UNTESTED*:

```
sed -i.bak  -e "/twm \&/,\$d" ~/.xinintc
```

This leaves a copy of the original file in `~/.xinitrc.bak`.

Comment: Other common ways to love this is by writing to a temporary file that is later renamed or by piping to `sponge` (a moreutils tool).  In the end, these three variation (counting the one in this answer too) does the same thing, either explicitly or behind the scenes.